# SnowFlake Query if an Id exists on each of the last 7 days

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

We INSERT new records every day to a table with say id and created_on column.

How do i identify if records with a particular identifier existed every day in the last 7 days ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TIME_TRAVEL(QUERY TEXT, DAYS FLOAT)
RETURNS VARIANT LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT AS
$$
  function run_query(query, offset) {
    try {
      var sqlText = query.replace('"at"', " AT(OFFSET => " + (offset + 0) + ") ");
      return (snowflake.execute({sqlText: sqlText})).next();
    }
    catch(e) { return false }
  }
  var days, result = [];
  for (days = 0; days < DAYS; days++)
    if (run_query(QUERY, -days * 86400)) result.push(days);
  return result;
$$;

CALL TIME_TRAVEL('SELECT * FROM TASK_HISTORY "at" WHERE QUERY_ID = ''019024ef-002e-8f71-0000-05e10030a782''', 7);
```

For the time travel query replace to work, put in an `"at"` as a table alias.
The return value is an array of day offsets when the query returns any value.
This will only work beyond `DAYS=2` if you have Snowflake Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the below query

```
select id,  sum(present) as total_count 
from
    (select id,feed_date, count(1) as present 
    from catalog_rca 
    where feed_date between '2019-11-19' and '2019-11-25'  
    group by 1,2) as temp
group by 1 having total_count = 7;
```