# Use dynamic value in snowflake time travel sql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to use dynamic value in time travel sql of snowflake

select * from my_table at (timestamp => (select max(COMPLETION_DATE) from my_table_2):: timestamp)

Comment: could you add clarification on what you are seeing? like any errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran something similar i got this error:

```
SQL compilation error: argument TIMESTAMP to function AT needs to be constant
```

I believe that a variable will work for this though:

```
set x = (select max(COMPLETION_DATE)::timestamp from my_table_2);

select * from my_table at (timestamp => $x);
```

**Edit for a view**

I don't think you can do this in a veiw, but you could do something like this probably with a UDF. See documentation here: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/udf-table-functions.html

Something like this:

```
create or replace function My_timetravel()
  returns table (column1 varchar, column2 numeric(11, 2))
  as
  $$
        set x = (select max(COMPLETION_DATE)::timestamp from my_table_2);

        select column1, column2 from my_table at (timestamp => $x);
  $$
  ;

select * from table(My_timetravel());
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I want to create a view on my_table1 based on specific timestamp value from my_table_2.  Variable option will not work in that case

Comment: hmm. I can't think of a way to do this in a view, but a UDF *might* get you what you are looking for. I'd have to know more about what the input and output you want is though.
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/udf-table-functions.html

Comment: edited with an example of a UDF that is related to your use case. I wasn't able to set up a full test situation for this tonight, so you'll definitely have to fiddle with it.

Answer (score 0):

Time travel can only be specified with a constant, which makes i impossible to parametrize (currently).

The only way to do this is via a stored procedure, where you can supply a query as text.
[I answered a similar question some days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59063404/snowflake-query-if-an-id-exists-on-each-of-the-last-7-days/59065812#59065812) with this procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TIME_TRAVEL(QUERY TEXT, DAYS FLOAT)
RETURNS VARIANT LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT AS
$$
  function run_query(query, offset) {
    try {
      var sqlText = query.replace('"at"', " AT(OFFSET => " + (offset + 0) + ") ");
      return (snowflake.execute({sqlText: sqlText})).next();
    }
    catch(e) { return false }
  }
  var days, result = [];
  for (days = 0; days < DAYS; days++)
    if (run_query(QUERY, -days * 86400)) result.push(days);
  return result;
$$;

CALL TIME_TRAVEL('SELECT * FROM TASK_HISTORY "at" WHERE QUERY_ID = ''019024ef-002e-8f71-0000-05e10030a782''', 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Session variable in Snowflake can work with query substitution and would help in the timestamp clause of your time travel query.  Currently, this feature is not supported inside a UDF so you would declare the session variable and then use it with your UDF:

```
SET x = (SELECT current_timestamp());
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_timetravel()
    RETURNS TABLE (c1 int)
    AS
    $$
        SELECT c1 FROM t1 AT (TIMESTAMP => $x)
    $$
    ;
```

SELECT c1 FROM TABLE(my_timetravel());

Comment: Sure, but still it remains a fact that in order to _automate_ any non constant time travel you have to use a stored procedure [for the time being].

Comment: Btw, nice to see that SQL variables can be set from an expression.  Is this brand new, or did I miss out on any announcement?  The docs doesn't have an expression example...